# How to retrieve Dynamics Sales data using REST API?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am integrating my application with Dynamics.

Now, I want to retrieve the data from the Dynamics Sales such as customer,products and order list from the sales organization.

I didn't find any web-api.

**Note : Done with the authorization**

Comment: Where are you calling this web api? Which creds you are using? How you are connecting? Show us the code

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webapi/web-api-samples) is some documentation.

To get you started:

To get the URL of the org's API, go to Settings > Customization > Developer Resources.

To retrieve Accounts you could do an HTTP GET on:
`https://myOrg.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/accounts`

To add some filtering:
`https://myOrg.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/accounts?$select=accountid,name&$filter=startswith(name,'a')&$top=5`

To retrieve a single account:
`https://myOrg.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/accounts(9bf473d6-47ae-e711-8108-5065f38a3ba1)`

Comment: I am getting 401 -Unauthorized error while using my org web-api URL : https://itc1234.api.crm8.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/accounts.(Note : access_token is valid only)

Comment: What happens if you try that URL directly in a browser where you have already authenticated to the D365 web client?